# SelectSingleNode to Evaluate LowerCase NodeSet value

Tags: c#, xslt, xpath

I am trying to get the value of an xpath expression in lower case using SelectSingleNode, is there an Xpath that can give me the lower case value of an evaluated xpath expression?

It is possible by having a xsl transform sheet, but is it possible with below?

The function expects to have nodeset type, below evaluates to string thus it throws exception. Is it possible to convert the returning string to a nodeset to make SelectSingleNode happy

```
        string xml = "<bac><test>Val</test></bac>";
        string xpath = "/bac/test/text()";

        var transpath = "translate(/bac/test/text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')";

        StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);

        XmlReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(sReader);            
        XPathDocument xmlPathDoc = new XPathDocument(xReader);
        XPathNavigator nav = xmlPathDoc.CreateNavigator();

        XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator = nav.Select("/");

        XPathNavigator navNode = nodeIterator.Current;
        var v = navNode.SelectSingleNode(transpath).Value;
       // expect val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an XPath expression that returns a primitive value (string, number, boolean) instead of a set of nodes you need to use the `Evaluate` method on `XPathNavigator`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8.aspx.

So for your code you could simplify it to

```
    string xml = "<bac><test>Val</test></bac>";
    string xpath = "/bac/test";

    var transpath = "translate(/bac/test,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')";

     XPathNavigator nav;
     using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
     {
        nav = new XPathDocument(sr).CreateNavigator();
     }
     string v = nav.Evaluate(transpath) as string;
```

On the other hand .NET is stronger on string operations than XPath 1.0 is so I would be tempted to use

```
 XPathNavigator test = nav.SelectSingleNode(path);
 string v = test.Value.ToLower();
```